# Always run Mongo Service

Tags: debian, node.js, vps, systemctl

I need to start mongo database for my NodeJs app on my VPS, I did :

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

So if I want to start it a boot I did :

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Buf what if mongod crash how can I restart it ? Do I need PM2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the *Restart=on-failure* option to mongod.service, under the *[Service]* section.

Systemd has several ways to customize service files that are distributed via packages, `systemctl edit` being the recommended one:

1. Run `systemctl edit mongod`
2. Add text:

   ```
   [Service]
   Restart=on-failure
   ```
3. Save and exit.
4. `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d/override.conf` will be created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
But how to "save and exist" with systemctl ? A way to use "nano" ?

Comment: Run `export EDITOR=nano` before using systemctl, like with everything else. If it dumped you into the Vim editor, `Esc :wq Enter` is save&exit.